# Rule.issuer in Webpack. What properties belong to it?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

Webpack's `Rule` option [presents two things](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-conditions) (in a full, not shortcut syntax): `resource` and `issuer`.

> In a `Rule` the properties `test`, `include`, `exclude` and `resource` are matched with the **resource** and the property `issuer` is matched with the **issuer**.

So, it is somewhat clear what properties are related to a `resource`:

```
{
    resource: {
        test: ...,
        include: ...,
        exclude: ...,
    },
    issuer: { ...boom?? }
}
```

But what properties are matched with the `issuer`? There is just nothing for issuer [in their docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-issuer):

> A `Condition` matched with the issuer. See details in Rule conditions.

And *details* do not explain `issuer`.

Why? They have created an option, but haven't decided on its properties yet?

Answer (score 11):

> They have created an option, but haven't decided on its properties yet?

The value of `issuer` is a [`Condition`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition). The most common  `Condition` is an object with `test`, `include` and/or `exclude` properties, which you have used for the `resource`. Everything you can use for `resource`, you can also use for `issuer`.

In fact, [`Rule.resource`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-resource) expects itself a `Condition`, excerpt from the docs:

> `Rule.resource`
>
> A [`Condition`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition) matched with the resource. You can either supply a `Rule.resource` option or use the shortcut options `Rule.test`, `Rule.exclude`, and `Rule.include`.

The only difference to the `issuer` is that there are shortcuts (`Rule.test`, `Rule.exclude` and `Rule.include`), because that's the majority of the use-cases. It roughly translates to:

```
resource: {
  test: Rule.test,
  exclude: Rule.exclude,
  include: Rule.include,
}
```

> And details do not explain `issuer`.

Clicking on [See details in `Rule` conditions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-conditions) leads to a description, which even contains an example. Excerpt:

> **Rule Conditions**
>
> There are two input values for the conditions:
>
> 1. The resource: An absolute path to the file requested. It's already resolved according to the resolve rules.
> 2. The issuer: An absolute path to the file of the module which requested the resource. It's the location of the import.
>
> **Example**: When we `import "./style.css"` from `app.js`, the resource is `/path/to/style.css` and the issuer is `/path/to/app.js`.

That is definitely an explanation, but maybe it isn't good enough, so I'll explain it in more details.

To illustrate the purpose of `issuer` I will use a contrived example, which could potentially be a use-case for it. Let's assume that you have some JavaScript code, which you would like to show to the user (the actual code) and at the same time you want to run that code in another part of the application. The code in question will be a simple greeting function.

**greeter.js**

```
export default function greet(name) {
  console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
}
```

If we want to show the source of `greeter.js`, we could read it from the file system, but because we'd like to run it in the browser, this is not an option. As we are using webpack, we can use the [`raw-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) to import the `greeter.js` file as a string instead of JavaScript. Assuming we have configured it, we can create a module that prints the source code.

**printer.js**

```
import greetSource from "./greeter";

export default function printSource() {
  console.log(greetSource);
}
```

In our entry point we want to use the greeter and the printer at the same time.

**index.js**

```
import greet from "./greeter";
import printSource from "./printer";

greet("World");

printSource();
```

Now we have a problem, because we've configured `raw-loader` for `greeter.js`, therefore `greet` will be a string, not a function and that will cause a runtime error. What we want is to import `greeter.js` in `index.js` as a regular JavaScript file, but we want to import it as a string in `printer.js`. We could use an inline loader definition, but that would be rather tedious.

This is where `issuer` comes in. Whichever JavaScript file is imported *from* `printer.js` should be passed through the `raw-loader`, and from any other file we'd like to use `babel-loader`.

We will define two webpack rules. Both rules target only JavaScript files, so we test for the `.js` file ending, for every file that is imported, this it the `resource`. We would like to know which file imported it (where the import statement was), this is the `issuer`.

**printer.js**

```
// Resource: greeter.js, Issuer: printer.js
import greetSource from "./greeter";
```

**index.js**

```
// Resource: greeter.js, Issuer: index.js
import greet from "./greeter";
```

For the rules, it means that we want to exclude `printer.js` as an issuer from the `babel-loader` rule, and include only `printer.js` for the `raw-loader` rule.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      loader: "babel-loader",
      resource: {
        test: /\.js$/
      },
      issuer: {
        exclude: /printer\.js$/
      }
    },
    {
      loader: "raw-loader",
      resource: {
        test: /\.js$/
      },
      issuer: {
        include: /printer\.js$/
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*Note: It's not necessary to include the `resource` option for the `raw-loader` rule and if you leave it out, it would apply the `raw-loader` to everything that is being imported in `printer.js`, which may or may not be what you want (think of including CSS to style the output)*

Bundling and running the above code will produce the following output:

```
Hello World!
export default function greet(name) {
  console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
}
```